# Why I can't open pdf file generated by this code? Adobe Reader error "invalid data format or invalid file"

Tags: java, pdf, printing

Why I can't open pdf file generated by this code? Adobe Reader error "invalid data format or invalid file". I want test my program using Microsofr PDF Printer before I get printer. Code work, retunt 0. I don't want use windows asking about printing detail. Why I can't open this file? It will work with normal printer?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main implements Printable, ActionListener {

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        FileInputStream textStream = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test.txt");

        try
        {
            textStream = new FileInputStream(file);   
/*
            String encoding = "UTF-8";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(textStream, encoding ));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while(( line = br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append( line );
                sb.append( '\n' );
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
*/ 
            }
            catch (Exception df)
            {
                System.out.println(df.getMessage());
            }

        DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, myFormat, null);

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(new Copies(1));
        aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
        aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));
        aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(2, 2, 210 - 4, 297 - 4, MediaPrintableArea.MM));


        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        System.out.println("Printing to default printer: " + printService.getName());

        DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();

        try
        {
            job.print(myDoc, aset);
            System.out.println("Druk");
        }
        catch (PrintException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new Main());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You consumed every last byte from `textStream`, then passed that same InputStream to the SimpleDoc constructor.  You are creating a Doc from an InputStream with no bytes left to read.

Comment: I edit my code (and post, you can see my actuall code above). I remove part using and displaying textStrem. Now it is not used before passing to constructor SimpleDoc. Error still exist. Did I understand you well? What should I do?

Comment: Can you share the generated pdf for analysis?

Comment: I want host it on https://nofile.io/ and on some other sites and i can't! Pages can't proses this file. It has got 0B size, when i open it in notepad++ pdf is empty (normal pdf has got a lot of characters).

Comment: OK. File host work here: https://megawrzuta.pl/download/c7ff906fb85d957a2ea23916eb4f8439.html

Comment: Are you sure that link works? I don't know where I can safely click, but the top lines read "**Pobierz** / Java Printing.pdf / 0 B", and if this file *is* 0 bytes then I don't need to download it to point out "well there is your problem".